# What is the command to get size of repository in linux?

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

```
:/$ du -sch $(ls -A)
5.6M    bin
0       boot
0       dev
0       docker-entrypoint-init.d
du: cannot read directory 'etc/ssl/private': Permission denied
2.3M    etc
0       home
9.8M    lib
0       lib64
0       media
0       mnt
0       opt
96K     pl
du: cannot read directory 'proc/tty/driver': Permission denied
du: cannot access 'proc/346/task/346/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/346/task/346/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/346/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/346/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0       proc
du: cannot read directory 'root': Permission denied
0       root
52K     run
4.3M    sbin
0       srv
0       sys
32K     tmp
563M    usr
du: cannot read directory 'var/cache/apt/archives/partial': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory 'var/cache/ldconfig': Permission denied'''
```

I have tried this.
I do not know the exact commands to check the space occupied by the repositories.
How to find the size of repositories in gerrit openshift.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following procedure:

1. Log in to the Gerrit server
2. Go to the Gerrit repository path

   cd GERRIT-SITE/git
3. Get the repositories size

   for repo in $(find . -wholename "*.git"); do du -hs $repo; done

Comment: I tried the same but I am not getting the size: 
4.0K    ./var/gerrit/review_site/git/LIVEDOC.git/refs/heads/etude
4.0K    ./var/gerrit/review_site/git/LIVEDOC.git/refs/heads/feature
40K     ./var/gerrit/review_site/git/LIVEDOC.git/refs/heads
4.0K    ./var/gerrit/review_site/git/LIVEDOC.git/refs/tags
4.0K    ./var/gerrit/review_site/git/LIVEDOC.git/refs/meta

This is how I am getting size.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the answer (I added the "s" option in the "du" command).

Comment: pl@gerrit-core-fd5869854-nnvsh:/$ du -hs $LIVEDOC
du: cannot read directory './proc/tty/driver': Permission denied
du: cannot access './proc/3130/task/3130/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/3130/task/3130/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/3130/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/3130/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot read directory './root': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory './var/cache/ldconfig': Permission denied
16G     .


Is this correct?

Comment: Have you executed "du -hs $LIVEDOC"? Why?!?

Comment: Yes I got the size using the command. Thankyou soo much.